# How do I get two variables to use in an .htaccess redirect?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect based on a cookie value AND a query string value but can't seem to get both values to return properly. I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} secret=([^;]+) [AND]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^file=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^downloads/(.*)/$ /downloads/%1/%2
```

and using the URL "/downloads/?file=protected/doc.pdf". I'd like the redirect to go to "/downloads/[secret cookie_val]/protected/doc.pdf"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no `[AND]` flag. Conditions are by default "anded" together.

Also, if you are requesting `/downloads/?file=protected/doc.pdf`, you've got one too many `/`'s in your regex:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}:::%{HTTP_COOKIE} ^file=(\w+):::secret=([^;]+)
RewriteRule ^downloads/(.*)/?$ /downloads/%2/%1
```

EDIT: Just realized that you were trying to access a previous `RewriteCond` back reference using `%2`, which is going to be blank because you've created another grouping with your `%{QUERY_STRING}`. So you need to combine the 2 vars into one `RewriteCond` and match against: `%{QUERY_STRING}:::%{HTTP_COOKIE}. Then you'll be able to backreference both the query string and cookie.

And the `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200` is to prevent rewrite engine looping.

Comment: Thanks, but I still am having difficulty. Will it make a difference if  /downloads/ is a virtual root (that's where the .htaccess resides)?

Comment: @DeweyOx If you're putting these rules in the `downloads` directory, change the `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /downloads/` and change the regex from `^downloads/(.*)/?$` to `(.*)/?$`

Comment: Still can't seem to get it to work. This is what I have: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /downloads/
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}:::%{HTTP_COOKIE} ^file=(\w+):::secret=([^;]+)
RewriteRule (.*)/?$ /downloads/%2/%1`

Comment: @DeweyOx and what does your URL look like and are you sure you have a cookie `secret=something`? Without the cookie, this rule won't match.

Comment: I've verified the cookie exists through the Web Developer plugin and can write it out using the technique found here:[link](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial.html) all looks good. I've certainly got the mod working and RewriteLogLevel at 4 which is giving me:`RewriteCond: input='file=sample/temp.pdf:::SESSID=2hdeunsktmtvkeiahi4e4c3on6; secret=ddc52b8t6f3e0a0c2a9e959d0047dd85; auth=ok;... __utmz=111379095.1348670414.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)' pattern='^file=(\w+):::secret=([^;]+)' => not-matched`